# secure method to pass value to a lightbox

Tags: php, session

there is need to pass values to a lightbox in a project i am working on , i know how to pass a variable through GET and through $_SESSION, but i wanted to know if there is a more secure way to do so .

$_GET shows value what are being passed when we use firebug or any developer tools . but $_SESSION dosen't . if i use $_SESSION then is there any drawback of using it ? or there is a more secure method which i am un aware of . i tried both methods and both are working fine as it should be , but can anyone clear me up with that using $_SESSION is much better or not.

for eg

```
www.example.com/quick_message/quick_msg.php?id=23
```

i am trying to protect the value 23

if i use $_SESSION this dosent appears on the link

```
www.example.com/quick_message/quick_msg.php
```

and also i can pass it to the colorbox and get the value inside colorbox by using $id=$_SESSION['id];

Comment: Please provide more details. What is a lightbox(is it lightbox plugin )? And what is being passed ? When `GET` method is used, values will be visible in the URL(in PHP, it will be available in `$_GET`) whereas in `POST` method(data can be accessed via `$_POST`), it won't.

Comment: If you need to securely transfer data back to the client, you should be using HTTPS.

Comment: a lightbox can be any lightbox for eg in my case its a colorbox , and a value can be any value as such id=3 or anything , i just want to clear my concept of which is a more secure method any why

Comment: What's a colorbox? It's impossible to give you a good answer without knowing what element your trying to protect. Got a example url, or a previous version with potentially unsafe values passed? And HTTPS solves alot of issues, but not everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use `POST` method for secure passed through `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST`